# How to dynamically create an image for instagram stories

Tags: react-native, instagram-api, instagram-story, react-native-view-shot

So I can already post a picture on my app to Instagram stories. However, every time a user clicks the button to share the image, the text and profile photo should be different on the image—like the image below. **Needs to be dyanmic.**

Right now, I'm thinking of just having a view that's off the screen, then using `react-native-view-shot` to get the picture & have it be dynamic that way. I was just wondering if there was a better way to do this.

[image]

Comment: Could you please add the problem you are facing and the desired output you want to achieve?

Comment: To be able to dynamically change a picture off screen in react-native.